# rails, wicked-pdf gem and é à ö characters showing incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, wicked-pdf

When I generate a PDF with text containing characters such as é è à and so on I do get funny characters instead.

I know this must be related to encoding.

I did try force_encoding("UTF-8") on the string with those characters with no success.

joel

Answer (score 8):

Add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to the top of your HTML view or in the head of your layout.

Answer (score 8):

You can pass as option:

```
encoding: 'utf8'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also add it as an option in the wickedpdf

```
 WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    render :pdf => "Paper",
    :template => "paper/paper.html",
    :page_size => 'A4',
     formats: :html, encoding: 'utf8',
    :margin => {:top => 40}
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Wicked's documentation for `pdf_from_string` doesn't really hint that you can pass options like this (sans controller/view). Eg this worked for me: `pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html, encoding: 'utf8')`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, add the following line at the beginning of your view:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

You can refer this link - https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/35 for more details.